# In mobile ,Multiple API calls on single button click in mail content

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, mobile, html-email

i need to call a API on the click of "a" tag in a html content of mail. The API is written in java, The problem is, when i click the "a" tag, it will redirect to any browser or will load on the same custom browser of the mail client application like Gmail(In Mobile). In some mobiles, this API get called 2,3 times in one click , how will we avoid this situation. Some one please give any suggestion. Please note that this issue is only with mobile, not in web browser.

> "a" tag

```
<a href="http://2686cd99.ngrok.io/application/service?id=werr345555" style="color: #fff; text-align: center; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none" target="_blank" >Button</a>
```

> API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "service", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private String requestForTicketReSchedule(HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
            @RequestParam(value="id") String id) {
        System.out.println("Called ----- "+id);

        return "success";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found that, when the time taken to receive response become higher, some mobile browsers is calling API multiple times. So in API, i just change the internal services as asynchronous and gave response immediately. Now the problem is solved.